# Beginning Java: Printing out a 5 pointed star using arrays

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been trying to print out a 5 pointed star but I keep on getting compile errors.

```
public class star 
{


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];
    int first = 5;
    int last = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)

       (char) star1[i][j] == "*";

        System.out.println(star1[i][j]);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    first cannot be resolved to a variable
    last cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token ")", throw expected after this token
    Incompatible operand types char and String
    j cannot be resolved to a variable at star.main(star.java:7)
```

I don't understand why we can't say `(char) star1[i][j] == "*"` How else can I assign an asterisk to `star1[i][j]`?

Comment: *"getting compile errors."*  Copy/paste the errors as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16116714/edit).  Also use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 0):

error is here

change

```
 int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];
 int first = 5;
 int last = 2;
```

to

```
int first = 5;
int last = 2;

int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];
```

and change   `for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)`  to  `for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){` //you missed `{`

Before using the variables you need to declare them.

public class star {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  int first = 5;
  int last = 2;
      int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)          
          for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
             System.out.println("*");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the compiler's errors:

```
public class star {


public static void main(String[] args){
    int first = 5;
    int last = 2;
char[][] star1 =new char[first][last];


for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){

 star1[i][j] = '*';

System.out.println(star1[i][j]);
}
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class star {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
}

O/P:**********

Above program is a simple program 
But in your program 
Your declaration is
int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];
    int first = 5;
    int last = 2;
You should declare the variables before you use that variables
 int first = 5;
 int last = 2;
    int[][] star1 =new int[first][last];

And then 
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

       for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){


       star1[i][j] = '*';

        System.out.print(star1[i][j]);
   }
  }
  }
}

The above code will compile successfully but the o/p is like
42424242424242424242
```